# Ruby for loop gives Nil class error when assigning array values

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a problem. I'm coding up a plug in for Google Sketchup and I'm trying to filter out array value and place the filtered values into another array. This is done like this:

```
for z in 0..points.length
  points2[z]=points[z][1]
end
```

Where "points" is a double array. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be better:

```
points2 = points.map {|p| p[1]}
```

Comment: @Jakcson'sMom tlewin's code does the same thing as yours: for each (array) element of `points`, assign the second value of that array to the corresponding place in `points2`.  Except that you overshoot the end of `points`, and this doesn't.  Perhaps that's why you're asking for help?  You didn't make clear what was wrong.

Comment: I guess, if it is a Nil class error, he didn't initialized the points2 variable. The above approach, it is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, you fix the definite bug of indexing past the end of `points` and the possible bug of failing to initialize `points2`.  And It's all-around better because it's more Ruby-like, clearer, less failure-prone, and there's no *need* to initialize `points2`.

Comment: And for the record, I up-voted your answer for all of those reasons, but your answer would be much better if you included those reasons *in* your answer, rather than just saying "this should be better".

Comment: @DarshanComputing You are right! When I saw your comment I realized it. Thanks!

Comment: @DarshanComputing: That's becausee edited his answer at a later time to this form :-)))

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is looping once to much. Using fake data:

```
ar = [1,2,3]
ar2 = []
for z in 0..ar.length 
#off by one! Should be one less. But then you should test for empty arrays...
  ar2[z] = ar[z]
end
p ar2 #[1, 2, 3, nil]
```

The other answers advocate `map` and they are right, but you could transform the for-loop into a less error-prone one like this:

```
for z in ar
  ar2 << z
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong? Fan of `for` loop that I am, you should use functional style, aka. Ruby way:

```
points2 = points.map { |element| element[1] }
```

Otherwise, you would have to post better example if you want people to diagnose your for loop.